# How to access the SMS/MMS database on Android without using "content://sms"

Tags: android, sms, database-connection, android-contentprovider

I recently read that the content provider `content://sms` shouldn't be used to access the SMS store, as there could be some mobile phones that might not know how to deal with it.

So, what would be the best way to access the SMS database in Android? How can I access mmssms.db (this should be the database I need to deal with, right?) directly from my own application to query text messages and conversations?

Comment: Having a look at http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/provider/Telephony.java shows that the Telephony Provider accesses the SMS / MMS database using 'content://sms'! So, I assume that this is seems to be the ONLY way to get to the SMS database right now, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

content provider is the only way to access sms-mms, programs like Handscent and my own are query the columns returned to ensure the applicable data is returned before the user can use the applications. The kernel supplies a basic core table and several manufacturers add on to this set.